# Any way to recover from a LoadPackage failure?

Tags: delphi, package

I'm writing a program that dynamically loads packages using SysUtils.LoadPackage. Some of these packages are third party and aren't very well behaved and are failing when InializePackage is called.

I'd like my program to continue to function after these failures. I've seen two different behaviors:

1. It throws an exception from somewhere in the package and terminates.
2. It throws and exception and returns control to the caller but the next time LoadPackage is called the program stops responding.

Any ideas on how to gracefully recover from these failures?

Comment: Not all exceptions are recoverable. If the third-party `LoadPackage` corrupts app memory, you're toast. So it depends.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I could host each package in a separate process. Then if the process dies the main application keeps on chugging.

Answer (score 2):

This could increase your load times, but you could create a program that simply attempts the loading and initializing of the package and returns a result your main application can interpret (maybe via a message) the success/failure.  That way if it fails it won't take down your main application, however if it succeeds you will be loading and initializing the package twice.

EDIT: As an optimization you could store the success/failure of the specific file name and package version so future runs of the program will go much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own package loader.  When you ignore all the IFDEFs it's a very short, simple routine.  It basically loads the library, verifies that it loaded, and then calls InitializePackage in a try block. If InitializePackage raises an exception, it unloads the library again.  If you had your own package loader, you could handle the exception however you wanted.

However, having said that, I agree with Craig that this isn't necessarily a good idea.  If a package is so poorly-written that it explodes in the `initialization` section, which ought to be so simple that there can't be any errors, do you really want that code running plugged into your program in the first place?  Best thing to do would probably be to try and get the third-party developers to fix their broken code.

Comment: Its not so much that I intend to run the buggy packages. I just need to load them long enough to gather information about them to display to the user. If the packages fails to load it will be marked as unusable.

Comment: @Kenneth: In that case, your idea about hosting them in a separate process would probably be the best solution.